# cant get serialize to work with javascript generated input fileds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery's `serialize()`. But in this case, it is not picking up my input fields that are created via some JavaScript code in a called PHP page in `$(document).ready(function ()`. I did an alert but the input fields were not in the JSON string.

The `serialize()` call is actioned by a submit action.

I tried both these but neither worked.

```
var dataString = $( "input" ).serialize();          
var dataString = $(this).serialize().replace(/\'/g,'\\\'');
```

I am guessing it is becuase they are generated at runtime.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
var url = "../js/contactmail.php";
var dataString = $(this).serialize().replace(/\'/g,'\\\'');                     
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: dataString,
    success: function (data) {
        var arraydata = $.parseJSON(data);           
    }
});
```

Code auto generated by JavaScript at runtime:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input data-prefix="thé" data-suffix="tea" id="tea" type="number" value="0"
           min="0" max="10" step="1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="input-group  ">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button style="min-width: 2.5rem" class="btn btn-decrement btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
                <strong>-</strong>
            </button>
            <span class="input-group-text">thé</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" inputmode="decimal" style="text-align: center" class="form-control " placeholder="" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">tea</span>
            <button style="min-width: 2.5rem" class="btn btn-increment btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
                <strong>+</strong>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. after some trial and error I have realised that serialize() uses HTML name Attribute and not the ID Attribute.  So the answer is to include `name = 'tea'`